# Colocation server: where to install ESXi?

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter, colocation

Sorry if this is a newbie question. I am colocating a 1U server and want to install ESXi on it. Given that a colo provider likely won't allow a USB key sticking out of the server, **what is the preferred way to install ESXi in production cases?**

Comment: ESXi can run in some VMs (particularly in other vmware solutions), but it is still a very... uncommon and not a production thing. So, you have to install vmware by accessing the console. The coloc provider has to provide some way for you to access your server, if he doesn't, you can't do too much. Actually, hardcore linuxers could try to install remotely an ESXi, without any console and usb access, but this is very hardcore thing, won't surely succeed and it is not what you are intended to do. ESXi has very annoying hw limits and install requirements.

Comment: Depends on the server. Care to share the make/model of the equipment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most server motherboards are shipping with one or more internal USB and SDcard ports.  Pop the top and take a look or just check the specs on the server.

Comment: Don't feel bad!  I still see companies quoting $1000 of spinning drive pairs for "OS/boot" on new VMware hosts.  Pretty wateful.  That said, make sure to have a spare USB or SDcard just in case.  You can run on a failed stick but it will prevent rebooting.  In case you have not used flash boot on ESXi in production, here are notes on pointing to persistent storage for scratch space: https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1033696

Comment: Newer servers have bootable SATA m.2 slots too